# Custom query: post__in parameter causes query to be empty

Tags: wp-query

I created a customizer setting where it's possible to choose a list of pages. This list of pages will be shown with a different style, only in pages using a specific template, together with more content.

Doing `print_r` on this setting shows an array of this type:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [page] => 701 )
    [1] => Array ( [page] => 156 )
    [2] => Array ( [page] => 1133 )
)
```

Then, i'm using a `foreach` loop to convert it in a suitable form for `post__in`, to add as arg for a `WP_Query`.

```
foreach ($services as $service) {
    $id = $service['page'];

    $id_list [] = $id;
}
```

where $services is obtained by `get_theme_mod` and contains the correct page ids.

Then, i'm passing it to `WP_Query` this way:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $id_list,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
);

$q = new WP_Query($args);
```

But query is returning no page despite the fact all ids are correct. As add-up, i may say that this query is being run on the homepage, and there is a standard query running after this; `wp_reset_postdata` is called.

Since i tried as well to hardcode my array and result is the same, what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Are those IDs `page` or `post` post type?

Comment: @Milo I didn't care until now. It's page for all of them

Comment: the you must set `post_type` to `page` or it will default to `post`.

Comment: It worked, thank you. Now i know one more thing :D